# laravel 2 tables have 1:n relationship with the same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a users table, a products table, and and an assets table. A user can have many assets, as can a product, meaning both Users, and Products have a 1:n relationship with assets. In Laravel how would show this relationship in Eloquent, is this a Polymorphic relationship, with the struct of the assets table columns being something like,

```
ID, type, file_path, ownable_id, ownable_type
```

Comment: You are the right way. Just change the ownabe_id, ownable_type to assetable_id and assetable_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your assets table columns should be

**id, type, file_path,  assetable_id, assetable_type**

Add this relation to your user and product model

```
    public function assets()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Asset::class, 'assetable');
    }
```

Next, add this relation to your asset model

```
public function assetable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

relation of user model

```
 public function assets()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Asset::class, 'assetable');
    }
```

relation of asset model

```
public function assetable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```